# Combine multiple typescript files into one js file when they contain a shared external module

Tags: typescript

I have 2 typescript files that share the same external module:

A.ts:

```
export module mymodule {
    export class MyClass {
    }
}
```

B.ts:

```
import a = require("A");
export module mymodule {
    export class MyOtherClass {
        new a.mymodule.MyClass()
    }
}
```

This all works nice and tidy in development and I enjoy type safety, dev support, debugging, etc. but for production, I would rather want to have it all in **one JavaScript file**.

Is that possible at all? I tried with --out and r.js but the combined files invariably end in nested define statements that make access to any class impossible.

If you are curious what we are trying to build: https://github.com/canoo/open-dolphin/tree/master/subprojects/client-javascript/js/dolphin

Comment: Highly recommend reading this https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript

Comment: Hm, yes. That page actually inspired me to do the whole thing. 

When they say "One effect of this is that it's not possible to use the --out compiler switch to concatenate multiple external module source files into a single JavaScript file." Does that mean that there is _no_ way?

Comment: You could hack something together that tried to merge the .js files, but from TypeScript itself there is no way. Are you wanting MyClass and MyOtherClass to merge into the same parent object?

Comment: Yes. All my classes live in the same external module and there is only one (but spread over many files). My goal was to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: The only way all your classes live in the same external module is if you only have one .ts file. See the "Needless namespacing" section of the linked page.

Comment: I feared you would say that :-) But I have actually just found a solution that works in my special case: having a starting all.ts class with no module definition, using r.js to do the bundling of the js files, substitute the external file references with local ones, rename the bundle file to all.js, and finally require "all" from HTML. *Puh*. Thanks for your time and the inspiration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, I could create a bundle for my special case.

Please see the "requireJs" task in https://github.com/canoo/open-dolphin/blob/master/subprojects/client-javascript/dolphin-client-javascript.gradle